# Jmeter timer for the http request should be run automatically every 40 minute ?

Tags: timer, jmeter, refresh, token

I would like to run a http request in thread group for jmeter. But it should be run per 40 minute. Therefore it should be run with frequency.

Also Im using jmeter 2.12 and jdk 1.7. So how can I configure this proceed and should I use any timer or anything?

```
 Thread group
   - Get token request
```

- It should be run automatically every 40 minute.

Please advice me,

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is correct:

- Thread Group (1 thread, loop count: forever or enough loops)

  - Get Token Request

    - [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) (Thread delay: 2400000)

In this case `Get Token Request` method will be fired every 40 minutes (40 * 60 * 1000) where 40 is minutes, 60 is seconds per minute and 1000 is milliseconds per second

Take a look at [How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) guide to learn how to use fresh token in another Thread Group if needed.

Comment: Basically, thread group includes http request for token. So I need to refresh my older token every 40 minute that it should be automatically run for to get new token.

Comment: In that case just adding a Constant Timer with thread delay of 2400000 ms should be quite enough

Comment: thank you so much @Dmitri T. I will try to do. If faced any issues, I 'll come back again

Comment: should I use a Loop controller or loop property of thread group?

Comment: When I use loop count of thread group, it couldn't move another thread group. So how can decide it ?

Comment: The only difference between "loop" in thread group and the Loop Controller is that in 1st case "Iteration" variable gets increased - it may impact test elements which rely on it like HTTP Cookie Manager. In case of Loop Controller "iteration" doesn't get increased and the whole test sequence is considered as 1 iteration.